# Multiple fields on the same row in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'd like to display a row with a label, a textfield and a checkbox for each item in a database. I've managed to do this except for the checkbox that's on a new line. I wan't:

```
<tr>
    <td>Label</td>
    <td>Input</td>
    <td>Checkbox</td>
<tr>
```

But all I get is:

```
<tr>
    <td>Label</td>
    <td>Input</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Checkbox</td>
</tr>
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

**EDIT:**

To generate the form I do:

**forms.py**

```
class AttributeForm(forms.Form):  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
        super(AttributeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for key in extra:
            self.fields[key] = forms.CharField(label=key, initial=extra[key], required=False)
            self.fields['delete_'+key] = forms.BooleanField(label='', required=False)
```

**views.py**

```
attribute_form = AttributeForm(extra=user)
return render_to_response('user.html', {'username': username, 'attribute_form': attribute_form})
```

**template (user.html)**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>{{ attribute_form.as_table }}</table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save attributes">
</form>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

My template ended up like this:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                {% for field in attribute_form %}
                    {% cycle '<th>' '' %}{% cycle field.label_tag '' %}{% cycle '</th>' '' %}
                    <td>{{ field }}{{ attribute_form.field.errors }}</td>
                    {% if not forloop.last %}{% cycle '' '</tr><tr>' %}{% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Save attributes">
    </form>
```

Comment: How are you generating this code? Show use the actual template or forms code. Is this for the admin or for a custom app?

Comment: Can you show us the template that Django uses for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.as_table` renders each form field in seperate table row. You should [render the form manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template).

Comment: Yes, that would be possible but very ugly since I'm generating the fields in the form I do not know how many fields I have or what they're called so I would have to use the same structure to generate fields in the view. If there's another way that would be better and more modular.

Comment: @olofom Another way to do what? You want Django (or some other tool) to know that any field with name 'delete_%s' should be grouped with field '%s' and to render them magically with one simple method, right?

Comment: maybe I don't understand the documentation completely but as I see it I need to hard code the name of each field within tr's and td's just like I was going to create the table entirely in HTML, which then makes the use of the Django forms useless?

Comment: @olofom You don't need to harcode the names. Just scroll the docs a little to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields). :-)

Comment: Ah, yes, ok, you're right, it worked in the end. If anyone else ever wants to know my template ended up like EDIT2 in my post.

Comment: @olofom You can move your first and last `<tr>`'s outside the cycle and get rid of `if`'s.

Comment: both yes and no, the first one is just to move out, but the last one still needs to cycle </tr><tr> so I can modify it a little bit, but the difference is almost none at all. Updated question with new code.